# What is preventing XAML from seeing my DLL and failing to compile?

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, compiler-construction, reference, workflow-foundation-4

I am trying to reference a DLL called WizardActivityPack with a XML type called "wiz:Step", but it's not appearing in the designer

[image]

Since the compiler is complaining about the type not existing, I used reflector to see what the compiled output is. The correct type does appear to be in the correct namespace in the correct DLL

[image]

What am I doing wrong, or what else can I do to get the XAML to "see" my DLL?

If it matters, I'm trying to compile in .NET 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that by upgrading each of the projects to version 4.5 and removing the XAML designer code of `"InitializeComponent();"` everything compiles and works fine.

I wish I had more to share for anyone who runs across this, but that is the fix for me.